# Iron Router with multiple parts

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I am using Meteor iron:router.

I have a template called by the name 'multi'.
So whenever I have paths like '/multi' or '/multi/BSC123' , I want 'multi' to be rendered.

So far I have used an array approach like this

```
Router.route('multi',{
    path:['/multi','/multi/:_id']
});
```

This works fine. But when I use this approach, my left nav bar which has a href link to 'multi' template is not shown. So apart from the above approach, can anyone suggest me other solution where I can have two paths and same template rendered and I should get the "id" too if present.

Comment: The pathFor does not work if I use the above method FYI

Answer (score 0):

In your router js file, just create two routes that render the same template:

```
Router.route('/multi', function () {
  this.render('multi');
});

Router.route('/multi/:_id', function () {
  this.render('multi', {
    data: {
      routeid: this.params._id
    }
  });
});
```

In your multi template:

```
<template name="multi">
   Path: {{pathFor 'multi'}}<br />
   ID: {{routeid}}<br />
</template>
```

Now if you access `/multi` the Path shows up as 'multi' and the ID is empty.  If you access `/multi/BSC123` the Path shows up as 'multi' and the ID is BSC123.